# authentication in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using zend auth for authentication. and everything works fine on my local machine.

But when i try to connect to remote server for database than problem starts.

It is not able to login. Is is some problem with session or what..?

```
     $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '123456',
        'dbname'   => 'saet'
    ));
    $form = new Default_Form_Login();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        //$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
        $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db);
        $adapter->setTableName('users')
                    ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                    ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                    ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');

        $credentialsArray = $this->_request->getParams();

        $adapter->setIdentity($credentialsArray['username'])
                ->setCredential($credentialsArray['password']);
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

        if ($result->isValid()) {

            $userInfo = $adapter->getResultRowObject(null, 'password');  
            // the default storage is a session with namespace Zend_Auth  
            $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();  
            $authStorage->write($userInfo);

            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Successful Login');
            return $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        } else {
            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->addMessage(array('error',"Invalid Username/Password"));
            return $this->_helper->redirector('login');
        }
```

now when i change the db details to remote server. it fails to log in. i m new in zend. and i get application error.

Comment: Impossible to answer with the current amount of information. Please add much more data about the setup and any error messages you get.

Comment: well, since "it fails to log in" it is probably giving an error message. What is it? And what is the application error message?

Comment: it just says "An error occurred
Application error"

Comment: please check php error log for further information. Maybe Database not available? table missing?

Answer (score 0):

To display errors change your application.ini file as follows
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
and then give us the error.